# VideoPlay crashes the Kernel with Mathematica 12.1

Tags: bugs, kernel, crash, video

I'm using Mathematica 12.1 on windows 10 (Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.1686])

When going to the Help file  about VideoPlay I tried the standard example and it crashes the Kernel.

For me it's easy to simulate I just use:

```
stream = VideoStream["ExampleData/Caminandes.mp4"]
Dynamic[stream["CurrentFrame"]]
VideoPlay[stream]
```

The errors I get:

[image]

[image]

When using another piece of code:

```
stream = VideoStream["ExampleData/bullfinch.mkv"]
Panel@Column[{
   Dynamic[stream["CurrentFrame"]],
   Slider[
    Dynamic[QuantityMagnitude[stream["Position"], 
      "Seconds"], (stream["Position"] = #) &], {0, 
     QuantityMagnitude[stream["Duration"], "Seconds"]}],
    Button[
    Dynamic[If[stream["Status"] === "Playing", "Pause", "Play"]],
    If[stream["Status"] === "Playing", VideoPause[stream], 
     VideoPlay[stream]]
    ]
   }, Alignment -> Center]
```

I can scroll through the frames but pressing Play will result in the same errors.
Using 1 or 2 monitors doesn't make a difference.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Same on macOS. I reported it an hour ago.

Comment: Same on Windows, filed a report 2 hours ago.

Comment: Should I file a report also?

Comment: Just reported it also.

Comment: This bug is being fixed via paclet update.

Comment: @ilian I have a quick question, is the entire wolfram system made out of small paclets including the kernel? If so can from now on (from 12.1) any installation of wolfram language be updated via paclet updates rather than reinstalls?

Comment: Many components are in paclet form, but the kernel, FE, runtime library and some other libraries cannot currently be updated in this way. I think that would be a desirable feature.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This bug has been fixed by a paclet update.

This would be applied automatically whenever the functionality is used in a new kernel (as long as the paclet manager has updated its local site index, which typically happens once per session).

To force an immediate installation, evaluate

```
PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[];

PacletInstall["FFmpegTools"]
```

which should result in FFmpegTools version 1.0.1 being installed.

Comment: Is version 12.1 available across all product lines including WolframOne / WolframDesktop not just Mathematica?

Comment: The 12.1 versions of these should be available soon, they are currently in the QA pipeline for final release